# Bash calculator

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bc, bash4

The following line is not working in my script:

```
a=$(echo "scale=3;(2*$j/(sqrt(3)*$i))" | bc)
a1=$(echo `expr "scale=3; $a^(1/3)"` | bc -l)
```

The error it is giving:

> Runtime warning (func=(main), adr=21): non-zero scale in exponent

I just want to have the value of cube root of 'a'. Somehow, I am not getting it. Please give some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
a1=$(echo `expr "scale=3; $a^(1/3)"` | bc -l)
```

Since you cannot use a non-integer value as a power in `bc`.

**Example to reproduce this error:**

```
bc -l
bc 1.06
sqrt(3)^(1/3)
Runtime warning (func=(main), adr=11): non-zero scale in exponent
1
```

**Solution:**

You can use this function to calculate cube root:

```
a1=$(bc -l <<< "scale=3; e(l($i)/3)")
```

Example:

```
i=8; bc -l <<< "scale=3; e(l($i)/3)"
1.999
```

Or use `awk` as mentioned by @fedorqui

Comment: Can you do `log(a)` and divide by `3` and then `antilog()`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `awk` for this instead of using complex `bc` syntaxs:

```
awk -v num=$bash_variable 'BEGIN{print num^(1/3)}'
```

For example:

```
v=3
awk -v num=$v 'BEGIN{print num^(1/3)}'
```

Returns: `1.44225`.

Or store the variable for a further usage:

```
var=$(awk -v num=$v 'BEGIN{print num^(1/3)}')
```